# Find all non-negative integral solutions $(n_1, n_2, ..., n_{14})$ to $\sum^{14}_{i=1} n_i^4 = 1599$.

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

> Find all non-negative integral solutions $(n_1, n_2, ..., n_{14})$ to
>   $\sum^{14}_{i=1} n_i^4=1599$.

I have a bit of difficulties to start the problem. Is anyone is able to give me a hint? Please I ask you to don't give me the solution to the question; I want to resolve by myself.

Comment: For one, we must have that each $n_i$ is $\leq \sqrt[4]{1599} < 7$, that is, one of $0, 1, \ldots, 6$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Suppose that $\sum_1^{14}n_i^4=1599$. Note that $1599\equiv 15\pmod{16}$.

The fourth powers of the even $n_i$ are divisible by $16$.

The fourth power of an odd number is congruent to $1$ modulo $16$. We have fewer than $15$ odd numbers to play with.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints**

1. Each $n_i$ must satisfy $n_i^4 \leq 1599$, and so $n_i \leq \sqrt[4]{1599} < 7$, so $0 \leq n_i \leq 6$.
2. Conversely, the largest $n_i$ must satisfy $n_i^4 \geq \frac{1599}{14}$, and so $\max_i n_i \geq 4$.
3. Since any permutation of a solution is a solution, we may as well first assume $n_1 \geq \cdots \geq n_{14}$.